# .net Janus Gridex, add multiple child rows, focus to the first row

Tags: .net, janus, gridex

In my table, I have 1 row, I add that, then I want to add a sub row in there(child table). When I add a second or third etc sub row, the focus always stays on the bottom row. If I add a new main row the focus always goes to the new main row not the bottom one like it does in the sub rows. 
I have tried all of the different setting that I can thing of but none will change the focus. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the row position after adding each row

Try this one , may be it will help you :

```
grdTest.Row = (from R in grdTest.GetRows()
               where (int)R.Cells["PKeyColumnName"].Value == PKeyValue
               select R).FirstOrDefault().RowIndex;
```

Here **"PKeyColumnName"** is a unique column that you can take any column from your table

And **"PKeyValue"** is the value for the unique column (last added row )